# Created GitHub repository, cannot push new files

Tags: git, github, push

I initialized github directory, added files, and pushed. However, the files do not appear.

I tried adding files individually, commiting, then pushing, entering in credentials and now I get error

```
Sonihal@RONNIE ~/MoveClient (master)
$ git pull
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.
From https://github.com/Sonihal/MoveClient
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

So I did a `git pull` and then another git commit and git push, and now it still says error.

How do I troubleshoot.

First time I created a repository of different name, no problem.

I tried creating this same repository three times today, even deleting and recreating. It's located here, https://github.com/Sonihal/MoveClient

The GitHub guides I'm using

http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1

http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

I'm tangled up like the GitHub cat is tangled in yarn (it's really late, had to make a funny)

Thanks!

*UPDATE*

When I created Repository, I selected checkbox to create ReadMe.

When I added two files to my git-enabled local directory and wanted to push, I had to first pull the ReadMe from the online repository with

`git pull origin master`

and then I can push the two files I added.

Comment: Use `git pull origin master` to pull master branch

Comment: @TimCastelijns Will try this out shortly

Comment: @TimCastelijns after much trying, your solution works. Will update post to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The actual solution was:

```
git pull origin master
```

GitHub repo was created with a `readme.md` file. It was in the actual first commit, autogenerated by GitHub. So that commit should have been pulled first to make further commits and pushes.

Comment: I ended up deleting and recreating the repository. Now I have new problem, which I'll post new question

Comment: Oh, so easy. Shame on me for not figuring out.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do `git add <file>` or `git add .` to add file(s) before you commit the changes

Comment: According to his first sentence, he did that